# What does the resistance of same order means in wheatstone bridge means?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, terminology, definition, order-of-magnitude

As we know that in order to increase the sensitivity of wheat stone bridge resistance are of same order but here what exactly order means can anyone give me an example of this order?

Answer (score -1):

Two numbers $A$ and $B$ are of the same order if
$$A=cB\quad \textrm{with} \quad 1<c<10$$
or
$$B=cA\quad \textrm{with} \quad 1<c<10$$
Two resistances $R_1$ and $R_2$ are of the same order if the numbers representing the values of $R_1$ and $R_2$ are of the same order. For example $R_1=5 \Omega$ and $R_2=7 \Omega$ or $R_1=5\cdot10^4 \Omega$ and $R_2=7 \cdot10^4\Omega$.

Comment: Make that 1<c<10 to be exact.